# New print of Minchas Yehuda

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, rashi

The popular commentary Sifsei Chachamim is a digest of supercommentaries on Rashi on Chumash. One of the commentaries I've frequently noticed he quotes is the **Minchas Yehudah**, by Rav Yehudah Leib ben Ovadia. I often want to look up this sefer, but I have failed to find a decent print of it online or in stores.

On Hebrewbooks there are three versions, with terrible print. [This one](https://hebrewbooks.org/45874) from 1609, [this one](https://hebrewbooks.org/38115) from 1654, and [this one](https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/40174) from 1678.

Was it ever reprinted, in its own sefer or as part of another set? In the popular [11 Meforshei Rashi HaMeoros HaGedolim](http://www.zolsefer.co.il/%D7%97%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%A9-%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%94%D7%92%D7%93%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%99-%D7%90-%D7%9E%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%99-%D7%A8%D7%A9-%D7%99.html) it is surprisingly absent. I'm fine with either online or in stores.

Comment: It is has been put on Wikitext - with the intention to slowly add the text - https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A0%D7%97%D7%AA_%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95%D7%93%D7%94 So far there's only one perek accounted for in bereishis and four in shemos

Comment: It seems from here that there does exist a 1989 edition - https://www.worldcat.org/title/sefer-minhat-yehudah-ve-hu-beur-al-pi-rashi-al-ha-humash/oclc/63548986/editions?referer=di&editionsView=true

Comment: @Dov yes I saw wikitext has good intentions ;-)

Comment: I look forward to your input :-)

Comment: @Dov I suppose that's a reprint edition. See details below: https://www.nli.org.il/he/books/NNL_ALEPH001089434/NLI